# Android Spoofing Phone Number?

Tags: android

Is there a way one can program to "Spoof" their phone number to the person receiving your call or does it require much more then just programming? I know there has to be a way... I seen spoof apps on the market, and I also have one as well, but it does not seem to be on the market any more. Although it still works, I just dislike how it is limited using up to three calls a day for two minutes each. I looked at the permissions for this Caller ID Faker and it requires.

- Network communication
- Personal information
- Storage
- Services that cost you money
- Phone calls

Only five different permissions setup in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it is not done from phone dude they routes the call through internet and the caller id is set there by no way can you use your gsm calling feature to fake a call as caller id is not contained in the sim but a serial no: (atleast in india)

Answer (score 0):

Caller phone number cames from operator, not from phone it self. So I will take a risk and answer it's impossible, as long operator does not support such operation.

Comment: but there is a serial number in your sim this serial no: and your imie is registered to the local nw operator tower which assigns the number there might be a possibility by impersonating another serial number which is no at the time registered with in any circles (at the time)

Comment: the reason is people are successfull in impersonating imie of a phone with different operators at the same time so it might be possible but not through android coding any way

Comment: So it is not possible through android coding as you say... does that mean this will require a different programming language or something?